# Binding a Backbone Collection to DOM element using rivets without extending backbone view

Tags: html, backbone.js, rivets.js

I'm new to html5. I want to bind backbone collection to DOM element using rivets without extending backbone view. I got code snippets like extending adapter, using rivets.bind but i dont know how to organize everything. Can someone explain me how to achieve this in steps?

Thanks in Advance

Update: We can do this if we follow the example provided in the link of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want to bind is the View, not the collection. The Collection is just data, an array of models if you wish. The View is what responds to user interaction, and that's where your rivets binding will be handled.

Check out Backbone.Marionette framework as its specialized CollectionView simplifies this even further, although you may go with a standard Backbone.View too.

Comment: I completely agree with your point. In some rivets tutorial i came across a point like it binds your data directly to DOM elements and thats the advantage over underscore where you need to bind the data via a template. So i thought we could bind data directly to DOM elements

Comment: Nop, but if I were you I'd checkout this article: http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/rivet-js-backbone-js-made-my-code-awesome/

Comment: I tried that one too.. For me its displaying { player:name }
instead of the name in the collection